# MS Access 2007 - SELECT ... INTO .... IN .... FROM linked_table_that_is_password_protected. How to incorporate password/UID?

Tags: database, ms-access, linked-tables

I am working in MS Access 2007. My database structure is as follows:

FE Access DB, contains linked tables from 2 BE databases:
- BE DB 1 is another Access DB where I am creating the records I am wanting to save
- BE DB 2 is a SQL database that I have linked ODBC tables from

To create the information that I save into the BE DB 1 I have need to create temporary tables. To avoid bloating my FE DB I am trying to create a temporary database in which the temporary tables will be created and accessed. I am using the UpdateTempTable function from this example:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/9753/Creating-and-using-Temporary-Tables-in-Microsoft-Access.html

The query that I am trying to run is:

```
SELECT zz.* INTO [temp_tbl_1] IN "C:\DIR\db_Temp.accdb" FROM (SELECT t1.* FROM lw_PRODUCT t1) as zz;
```

db_Temp.accdb is my temporary database, lw_PRODUCT is the ODBC linked table in my FE DB. When I try to run this query directly it requests the user id and password for the linked table, when I enter it the results of the query are correctly input to the temporary table in the temporary database.

My question is: How can I programmatically include the password and userid for the ODBC linked tables when they are used in a query that creates a temporary table?

If I run the simple query in my FE DB:

```
SELECT * FROM  lw_PRODUCT;
```

I am not prompted for a UID or password.

Comment: *a SQL database*...SQL is a language that an RDMS uses including MS Access. No single entity, not Microsoft, Oracle, IBM or open source affiliates owns it. You may have meant SQL Server database. This is not to split hairs but MS Access can link tables from any popular RDMS and thus integration differs accordingly.

Comment: Secondly, temp tables most like should be kept in FrontEnd apps as each user will not overwrite each other during such a process (assuming they each use their own FE connected to one centralized BE).

Comment: Parfait, you are correct I meant a SQL Server database. The concern I have with the temporary tables in the FE is bloating of the FE database. These tables are created temporarily as intermediate steps then deleted after use. I have tried using compact and repair in the past and did not see a reduction in size of the database which is what ultimately led me to splitting into a BE and FE.

Comment: That should not be a reason to split databases. Split architecture is how all software and web applications run, not just MS Access where application is separated from database. The very fact they are temporary uses suggest temp tables should be used in FE as part of application runtime. All your users should have individual copies of FE on local machines connected to server stored BE. Do not be concerned about bloating in near term, run compact periodically -even keep a server FE to be copied after design updates to users' machines, so effectively destroy/copy FEs periodically!

Comment: That probably makes more sense at this point, I have a user group of less than 10 people so managing the FE shouldn't be too terrible. Managing the temporary tables in the FE will also eliminate my current problem, I appreciate your insights!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as temporary tables in MS ACCESS. All tables are physical tables. If you want to use temporary tables, you must take care of creating a table, using the table and finally dropping the table.

As previously suggested, you should do this in your front-end side as the usage of temporarily table thought for each connection/session only.

If you are thinking about sharing the temporary table among other users then you have misunderstood the concept of temporary tables.

You can simply link both back-end tables using ODBC (and using table definition and connect property if you create manually) and use them as normal tables without having to enter login details.